# JQuery JSON POST request to ASP.NET MVC controller does not hit end-point, but manual use of route works correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET application which consists of a front-end that contains a form whose data I want to pass through to my C# back-end. To do this I am using a JQuery post request to serialise the form data and send it through to the controller using JSON. Below is my Javascript code that calls the controller route;

```
$(".data-submit").on("click",
        function(event) {
            var formArray = $("#amend-form").serializeArray();
            var json = JSON.stringify(formArray);

            $.post(windowLocationOrigin() +
                "/Instruction/AmendData", 
                json, 
                function (data) {
                    alert("api endpoint called");
                });

        });
```

And here is the controller end-point being called

```
        [Route("[controller]/AmendData")]
        public IActionResult AmendPortingData([FromBody] string json)
        {
            return Ok(json);
        }
```

When I submit this form through my front-end, the onClick JS event is called and the post request is sent, however the controller end-point is never hit. I have a breakpoint on the `return Ok(json)` line which is never triggered after the form is submitted.

If I check in the developer tools I get a 500 error with message: `POST https://localhost:44358/Instruction/AmendData 500`

However if I then submit a request to this url `https://localhost:44358/Instruction/AmendData?json=123` the end point is hit correctly and I can see the value `123` in my debugger.

However I want to be able to send my data through the post request body, and not through the url as the form being submitted is large and contains too much data to be sent over a GET.

I have tried adding the `[HttpPost]` attribute to the controller end-point but this produces the exact same behaviour, except it doesn't allow the GET url to work.

Comment: Try changing to: `var json = { json: JSON.stringify(formArray) };`

Comment: @freedomn-m This fixed my problem, thanks! Could you explain why not doing this was causing the problem? I'd like to know exactly why this caused the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Controller Action:

```
public IActionResult AmendPortingData(string json)
```

is expecting a parameter named `json`.

When you call this with:

```
 $.ajax({ url: url, data: "string" });
```

the data passed does not have a parameter name so the default Model Binder can't determine which part of the data to apply to that parameter.

This works with:

```
http://url?json=string
```

as you specify the parameter name `?json=`, if you called your action with

```
http://url/string
```

then it would again not recognise "string" as being for parameter "json" and not work (though likely give you a more useful "can't find data for parameter" error) (assuming no additional routing of course).

By giving your string parameter a name, the default Model Binder will be able to match the string to the parameter name:

```
$.ajax({ url: url, data: { json: "string" }});
```

---

An alternative is to add a Model Binder that will take any POST'd string and pass it to the single parameter - but the above is generally cleaner and easier to maintain.

---

Adding `[HttpPost]` restricts the action to just that verb (so, as an aside, adding `[HttpPost][HttpGet]` makes it unusable as it must be POST and it must be GET).

---

If you are building your form from a viewmodel, then you can use that viewmodel directly in the action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel viewmodel)
```

and pass directly:

```
$.ajax({ url: url, data: $("form").serialize() });
```

and the default Model Binder will map the names of your inputs to properties on the viewmodel.

Comment: Really fantastic answer. Thanks for taking the time to write it up. I think my main issue was thinking that the binder would be able to map the JS variable name to the C# parameter name. Hence why I didn't think you'd need to specify a name for the POST body data within JS.

Comment: Confusingly, that does work in some cases, specifically if you do `$.ajax({url:url, data: { json }})` should also work ... in Chrome - it's browser specific so always worth adding `data: { json: json }` otherwise you'll have hard to find bugs that work for you but not for someone else until hours later you find they're using a different browser... (1st hand experience!)